# Render page dynamically on client side using vanilla js

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6, routes, history

Suppose, I have js files along with the router.

// index.js   -> / (route)

Home Page

// about.js    -> /about (route)

About Page

1. I have configured the code using history api such that it can go to /about from home page. But, when I directly land on localhost:5500/about, it gives me 404 error. Is there a way to make it land on localhost:5500/about directly and if it lands on any other page such as localhost:5500/err, it should fallback to "/" route.
2. Also, how can I manage conditions such as localhost:5500/about/{user_id} using dynamic routing. All the solutions I found uses server to fetch page but I want the routing to handled at the client side itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

The browser requests a URL from the server. The server responds with something.

Ideally this should be the page that was requested. Good implementations of heavily client-side applications will use server-side rendering so that this is the actual page that was requested. (This obviously doesn't happen client-side.)

Less ideally, a server is configured to serve up the applications bootstrapping HTML document for all URLs that would normally 404, then client-side code and pick up and look at `location` to determine what to render. (This, again, needs the server to be set up to do this).

Even worse is to do the same thing, but by way of making that bootstrapping HTML document the 404 error page. (Again, needs the server to be set up that way, and so gives everybody (including search engines) 404 errors.